# Is there a way to check or validate the props coming through directly from the related type or Interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this simple component which takes as props an array of strings (tabs) and children (component to be rendered). I want to check if the provided children are of the same length as the tabs array directly from the type declaration or any cleaner way to handle this check.

```
type TabsProps = {
  tabs: string[];
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
};

const Tabs = ({ tabs, children }: TabsProps) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

  const componentsToRender = Children.toArray(children);
  
  //TODO Handle this check in a cleaner way
  if (componentsToRender.length !== tabs.length) {
    throw new Error('Your components or tabs are not of equal length');
  }

  const handleTabSwitch = (index: number) => {
    setActiveTab(index);
  };

  return (
    <TabWrapper>
      <TabHeader tabs={tabs} activeTab={activeTab} onTabSwitch={handleTabSwitch} />
      <Dividers />
      <TabContent>
        {componentsToRender.map((component, i) => {
          return activeTab === i ? component : null;
        })}
      </TabContent>
    </TabWrapper>
  );
};

export default Tabs;
```

As shown in the code snippet, I handled it with a simple if condition that throws an error
But I would rather it be handled while coding instead of at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a type that checks whether the length of the array of children matches the length of the array of tabs :

```
type TabsProps<T extends string[]> = {
  tabs: T;
  children: { [K in keyof T]: ReactNode };
};

const Tabs = <T extends string[]>({ tabs, children }: TabsProps<T>) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

  const componentsToRender = Children.toArray(children);

  const handleTabSwitch = (index: number) => {
    setActiveTab(index);
  };

  return (
    <TabWrapper>
      <TabHeader tabs={tabs} activeTab={activeTab} onTabSwitch={handleTabSwitch} />
      <Dividers />
      <TabContent>
        {componentsToRender.map((component, i) => {
          return activeTab === i ? component : null;
        })}
      </TabContent>
    </TabWrapper>
  );
};

export default Tabs;
```